The ErrorBoundary component is not displaying in the Blazor App
I'm trying to create a error handler for a Blazor App.
I've reviewed the offical instruiction on Microsoft Learn
Here is my MainLayout
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<FluentLayout>
    <FluentHeader>
        -----
    </FluentHeader>
    <FluentStack Class="main" Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal" Width="100%">
        <NavMenu />
        <FluentBodyContent Class="body-content">
            <div class="content">
                @Body
            </div>
        </FluentBodyContent>
    </FluentStack>
    <FluentFooter>
        <a href="https://www.fluentui-blazor.net" target="_blank">Documentation and demos</a>
        <FluentSpacer />
        <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor" target="_blank">About Blazor</a>
    </FluentFooter>
</FluentLayout>

<article class="content">
    <ErrorBoundary @ref="errorBoundary">
        <ChildContent>
            @Body
        </ChildContent>
        <ErrorContent>
            <p class="errorUI"> A rotten gremlin got us. Sorry!</p>
        </ErrorContent>
    </ErrorBoundary>
</article>


@code {
    private ErrorBoundary? errorBoundary;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        errorBoundary?.Recover();
    }
}

I enabled the detailed error, I can see the error log in the console but can't display the ErrorBoundary component in the page.

blazor.web.js:1 [2024-07-09T11:14:01.582Z] Error:
System.InvalidOperationException: Current count is too big!    at
Web.Host.Components.Pages.Counter.IncrementCount() in
Web\Components\Pages\Counter.razor:line
22    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallbackWorkItem.InvokeAsync[T](MulticastDelegate
delegate, T arg)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem
callback, Object arg)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback`1.InvokeAsync(TValue
arg)    at
Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components.FluentButton.OnClickHandlerAsync(MouseEventArgs
e) in /_/src/Core/Components/Button/FluentButton.razor.cs:line 217
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task
task)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task
taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)


did you try packing the  inside a  instead of an  ?  next thing i would consider would be a custom Element and then pack the  inside this

didn't work unfortunately

if you want to access the Exception you can try this:
<ErrorContent Context="Exception">
  <p class="errorUI">
     @Exception.Message
  </p>
 </ErrorContent>


before displaying exception message, I can't display any thing in ErrorBoundary, even a static text

why you can't!!!?  You can add any text you want in the content

the reason was ErrorBoundary  in out of FluentBody. I moved it in, and it works now

@OguzKaanAkyalcin - please add Your Answer showing the code change that works now. (After 48 hours, you can return and accept [checkmark] your own answer.)

The reason is ErrorBoundary is out of Fluent body.
Changing that like the below worked.
<FluentBodyContent Class="body-content">
    <div class="content">
        <CustomErrorBoundary @ref="errorBoundary">
            <ChildContent>
                @Body
            </ChildContent>
            <ErrorContent Context="Exception">
                <div class="blazor-error-boundary">
                    <h3>@Exception.GetType()</h3>
                    @Exception.Message
                    <button class="close-button" onclick="@errorBoundary.Recover">&times;</button>
                </div>
            </ErrorContent>
        </CustomErrorBoundary>
    </div>
</FluentBodyContent>

